# where to get spring mock libs?

Tags: web-services, spring, mocking, spring-3

i want to use `org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest`

and it doesnt appear on any of these links i download from the [official Spring website](http://www.springsource.org/download/community?project=Spring%2520Framework)

no idea where i can get the mock libs as it doesnt appear on the spring framework libraries . any suggestions?

i am basically trying to use :

```
 private MockHttpServletRequest request;
    private MockHttpServletResponse response;
```

to unit test my controllers. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the libs here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test/2.5

Spring-test